# How do I turn the background of the menu overlay to a blur (or "frosted glass") of what it covers up?

Tags: html, css, menu, overlay, gaussianblur

Setting up my website portfolio site following this yt tutorial from Traversy Media (https://youtu.be/gYzHS-n2gqU). I want to turn the menu (which is simply transparent) into one that simply applies a blur to what's underneath it.

I have tried inputting filter: blur(5px); and all sorts of combinations of that in the css but it never works :(

```
// Menu Overlay
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1; //this is where you control the opacity of the menu. 1 = opaque, 0 = transparent
  visibility: hidden;

  &.show {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  &-branding,
  &-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*background: darken($primary-color, 5);*/
    background: transparentize(
      $color: darken($primary-color, 5),
      $amount: 0.05
    );
    list-style: none;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    @include easeOut;

    &.show {
      // Slide in from top
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

You can see the menu code in action on the portfolio site I have created at mashal.co/  It's under construction still, so don't flame me too hard for it haha.

Right now, all it is a minor transparent overlay when I click the menu button in the upper right. the code I provided above is only for the right half of the the overlay.  Thanks a ton for any and all help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such as blurring or color shifting to the area behind an element. Note that it is still an experimental property:

- Chrome, Opera, Chrome for Android: supported after enabling "Experimental Web Platform Features "
- IE, Firefox: not supported

What I'd advise you is to play around with a simple [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) CSS property to apply the blur you want.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried to put in a filter in practically every place imaginable in the code but the best I get is that everything in that half of the menu gets blurred...including the text which is not what I want. Do you know how I can simply blur the background without the text?